# Como funciona yield?

Tags: python, yield

Encontré este código que usa recursividad y `yield` pero no logro entender la lógica de como funciona yield para imprimir el par `(num, num)` y de por qué dos veces pone `yield` h en dos bucles distintos.

```
def hanoi(n, src, dst, tmp):
    if n <= 0:
        pass
    else:
        for h in hanoi(n-1, src, tmp, dst):
            yield h
        yield (src, dst)
        for h in hanoi(n-1, tmp, dst, src):
            yield h
```

Comment: Hola Mauricio. Bienvenido. ¡Muy interesante pregunta pero la explicación es larga, e involucra bastantes conceptos! Espero que mi respuesta sea clara. Puedes pedir en comentarios cualquier aclaración adicional que precises.

Answer (score 12):

### `yield` y generadores

La instrucción `yield` es una especie de `return`, pero a diferencia de este último no da por terminada la función, sino que puede reanudarse después en la línea siguiente a donde haya ocurrido `yield`.

Esto puede usarse para objetivos diversos (por ejemplo, para implementar la idea de "corutina" y posibilitar que varias tareas avancen a la vez "por turnos", pasando el turno de una a otra con el `yield`). O, más frecuentemente y como es tu caso, para implementar generadores.

Cuando una función incluye la sentencia `yield`, python la trata de forma especial. En el momento que "ejecutas" la función, en realidad no se ejecuta nada, sino que se crea un generador, que es un tipo especial de objeto. Puedes guardar ese objeto en una variable y posteriormente, cada vez que hagas `next()` sobre ese objeto, el código de la rutina se ejecutará hasta llegar al siguiente `yield` y allí se pausará. El valor especificado tras `yield` será lo que retorne `next()`.

Un mínimo ejemplo puede aclarar las cosas:

```py
def ejemplo():
   a = 0
   yield a
   a += 1
   yield a

g = ejemplo()
# No se ejecuta nada aún, g es un generador
r = next(g)  # r vale 0
```

Al ejecutar `ejemplo()`, la función no se ejecuta, pero se crea el objeto generador que nuestro programa recoge en la variable `g`. Al hacer `next(g)` se ejecuta la función, guarda un 0 en `a` y hace `yield a`, lo que causa que `next(g)` termine retornando 0 (que era el valor de `a`). Pero la rutina puede ser reanudada. Si hacemos de nuevo `next(g)` continuará en la línea siguiente, hará `a+=1` y el siguiente `yield a` "retornará" un 1, que será el valor retornado por ese `next(g)`.

¿Qué pasa si hacemos `next(g)` una vez más? En ese caso la rutina se reanuda en la línea siguiente al último `yield`, y como ya no hay más líneas, terminará. En este caso la terminación contiene un `return None` implícito, como todas las funciones python, que retornan `None` cuando alcanzan su final. Pero este `None` no ha sido retornado por un `yield`, sino por un `return` normal (aunque implícito).

Esto es detectado por Python. Cuando un generador retorna con un `return` normal en vez de `yield`, python genera la excepción `StopIteration` y a partir de ese momento ya no tiene sentido hacer más `next(g)`, pues se generará siempre esa excepción que señala que el generador ha terminado. Así:

```py
>>> g = ejemplo()
>>> next(g)
0
>>> next(g)
1
>>> next(g)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

### Generadores y bucles `for`

Todo lo anterior lo "hace invisible" python si lo usas en un bucle `for`, pues internamente lo que hace python es crear el generador y llamar a `next()` repetidas veces (una para cada iteración del `for`), hasta que se produzca `StopIteration` en cuyo caso abandona el bucle.

Por tanto puedes hacer:

```py
for r in ejemplo():
   print(r)
```

Y saldría 0, 1 y terminaría.

### Hanoi y recursividad

En tu caso el `yield` se complica con la recursividad, lo que hace bastante difícil de leer y entender ese código.

La función `hanoi()`, ya que contiene instrucciones `yield`, no es una función normal. Cuando la ejecutes dentro de un programa, por ejemplo así:

```py
hanoi(5, 1, 2, 3)
```

no verías nada. No se ejecuta realmente sino que se crearía el generador. Tendrías que ir haciendo `next()` sobre él para que la ejecución tuviera lugar. O también puedes ejecutarlo como parte de un `for`, así:

```py
for movimiento in hanoi(5, 1, 2, 3):
    print(movimiento)
```

En ese caso, como ya explicamos, la maquinaria del `for` crea el generador y va haciendo `next()` sobre él, almacenando en la variable `movimiento` los sucesivos valores que `next()` vaya retornando, que me limito a imprimir.

Entonces, en el primer `next()` comenzaría la ejecución del generador, que comenzará mirando si `n` es 0 (si lo fuera, no hace nada, con lo que se produce el fin de ejecución del generador, un `return None` implícito, una excepción `StopIteration` y el final del `for`).

Si no es el caso, se entra en el `else`, que usa recursividad para resolver el problema. La recursividad en este caso parte de la idea de que mover una torre con N discos de `src` a `dst` puede resolverse moviendo primero los N-1 discos superiores desde `src` a  `tmp`, después el disco que queda de `src` a `dst` y por último volviendo a mover los N-1 discos de `tmp` a `dst`.

Para hacer el movimiento de los N-1 discos llama de nuevo a `hanoi()`. El que funcione eso es fuente inagotable de maravilla, y la magia de la recursividad.

En esta implementación concreta para invocar a `hanoi()` de forma recursiva, ya que no es una función normal sino un generador, lo hacemos de nuevo dentro de bucles `for`. Iteramos sobre los movimientos que produce `hanoi()` para el problema N-1, y cada uno de esos movimientos (guardado en `h`) lo "retornamos" a su vez al bucle principal haciendo `yield h`. Cada una de estas `h` será una tupla (¿por qué? sigue leyendo)

Una vez "retornados" los movimientos para los N-1 discos iniciales, hacemos `yield (src, dst)` y **aqui** es donde retornamos la tupla que mueve un solo disco. En el bucle `for` que hicimos antes, la llamada recursiva a `hanoi()` producirá a su vez más llamadas recursivas, hasta que eventualmente se alcanzará un momento en que `n` sea 1, es decir, haya que mover un solo disco. En ese caso `n-1` vale cero, por lo que ninguno de los bucles `for` que hay dentro llega a ejecutarse (todos terminan antes de iterar porque el primer `next()` eleva `StopIteration`). Así que para el caso `n=1` el único `yield` que llega a ejecutars es el `yield (src,dst)`, que indica como mover (trivialmente) un solo disco de `src` a `dst`.

El siguiente `for` funciona de modo análogo para mover los N-1 discos que estaban en la aguja `tmp` de nuevo a la aguja `dst`.

### Para rematar: `yield from`

En Python 3 se añade la sintaxis `yield from`, que permite a un generador "delegar" su trabajo en otro generador.

Es decir, si dentro de un generador tienes:

```py
yield from sub_generador()
```

entonces python conectará tu generador con el subgenerador, de modo que todos los `yield` que haga el subgenerador es como si los hubiera hecho el tuyo. Cuando el sub-generador se agote (eleve `StopIteration`) el `yield from` se dará por terminado y se seguirá por la línea siguiente. Es como si en el generador principal hubieras puesto:

```py
for valor in sub_generador():
    yield valor
```

¡Un momento! ¿No es esto lo que tenemos precisamente dentro de la función `hanoi()` (aunque en este caso y debido a la magia de la recursividad el subgenerador es de nuevo la misma función).

Eso implica que podemos reescribirlo así:

```py
def hanoi(n, src, dst, tmp):
    if n <= 0:
        pass
    else:
        yield from hanoi(n-1, src, tmp, dst)
        yield (src, dst)
        yield from hanoi(n-1, tmp, dst, src)
```

Esta sintaxis, si no más clara (que en mi opinión lo es), al menos es más corta.

Comment: se puede decir que los generadores son como cursores donde tienen atributos especiales para iterar